# send parameters from the javascript tag to javascript file

Tags: javascript, parameters, tags

Is it possible?, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">google.load("swfobject","2.2")</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myswf.js?swf=animate01"></script>
```

in the myswf.js file :

```
swfobject.embedSWF("flash/"+swf+".swf","ID","258","371","9.0.0","",{},wmode:"transparent"},{});
```

Is it possible to do something like this?
thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is yes, but you would need to create a separate JavaScript file to parse all your  elements and look for those parameters.

For what it looks like you're trying to do there's a most likely a simpler solution.

edit:

Here's some code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function doEmbed(name) {
    swfobject.embedSWF("flash/"+name+".swf","ID","258","371","9.0.0","",{},wmode:"transparent"},{});
  }

  doEmbed("animate01");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could register a global var called swf in the first script. References to a varaible called swf in javascript interpreted after will reference this object as its global. Its not a good practice to do this but it works. I would rather all my code working with that variable be in one place :) That way i avoid dangerous side effects and ugly globals littering my javascript...